# .Net core + React + PostgeSQL in Docker

Tags: .net, reactjs, postgresql, image, docker

Can I build backend, frontend, and DB in differing containers with connections using Docker?
I tried to build .net core 3.1 + React js in one container, and get an issue '"npm install" error code 9009'.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) for this. Docker compose will allow you to start all of your applications at once as well as allow you to network your containers so that they can communicate with each other. There's also a tool called [`architect`](https://github.com/architect-team/architect-cli) that will handle the networking for you if you write a few config files for your services if you don't want to do that yourself.

You probably don't want to build all of these services in one Docker container as your applications and database have too many different dependencies. You would want a different container for each one. There is actually an example in the `architect` repo which seems like a very good model for your app. Have a look [here](https://github.com/architect-team/architect-cli/tree/master/examples/react-app).

As for the `npm install` issue, it looks like that could be solved by using a node-based base image for your Docker image. A common base Docker image for a react app would be node:12-alpine, which already has `npm` installed.